# Is POSIX pselect available in Perl?

Tags: perl, sockets, network-programming, posix

Is POSIX **`pselect`** available in Perl?  A CPAN module is fine also.

Comment: Could you fake it with POSIX::sigprocmask and select? What sort of application do you have in mind?

Comment: Nothing in particular at the moment, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>As far as I can tell (in February 2010), neither the POSIX module nor any other provides support for the `pselect()` function.</s>

Since February 2010, as [Wumpus Q. Wumbley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2404501/wumpus-q-wumbley) points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198876/is-posix-pselect-available-in-perl/2301130?noredirect=1#comment35698769_2301130), a module [POSIX::pselect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX%3A%3Apselect) now exists, at revision 0.03 on 2014-04-26 (but the link is the version-neutral permalink).  Versions 0.01 and 0.02 were released in June 2011; 0.03 in August 2012.

Comment: @Jonathan:  Any idea why it's not provided?

Comment: @Robert: Two guesses - maybe a combination.  (1) It is too new - it is a relatively recent addition to POSIX, and may not be available everywhere.  (2) The signal masking semantics in pselect() don't fit particularly easily into the Perl framework.

Comment: Time has passed, and this answer has been wrong longer than it was right. [POSIX::pselect exists now](http://search.cpan.org/~gfuji/POSIX-pselect-0.02/lib/POSIX/pselect.pm)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: thanks for the information.  I've updated my answer to reflect modern reality.  I'm pretty sure I'd not revisited the question/answer since February 2010.